WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type even after adding previous release
I already added the JAR file in the library and even added previous release because the import for web driver is still not showing enter image description here
I tried adding many jars because even when adding the stable version, import web driver is still not wshowing

You mean to say, it is not showing install suggestion when you hover on the WebDriver keyword? Your query is not clear. Are you downloading the jars manually? Any restriction for not using Maven to add dependencies?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. This includes HTML.

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You need to add
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

